# Get some text with java + selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium

I want to get only the text **"Invitation sent to xxxxx"**, I do not want to get what's inside the

```
<button class="action" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-3995="3995">
          Visualizar perfil
 </button>
```

**I'm getting the text this way:**

```
String pessoapopu = driver.findElement(By.className("artdeco-toast-message")).getText();                
System.out.println(pessoapopu);
```

**Page structure:**

```
<div class="artdeco-toast-inner" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-3994="3994">
    <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="success-pebble-icon" class="artdeco-toast-icon"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" height="24px" x="0" y="0" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="artdeco-icon"><g class="large-icon" style="fill: currentColor">
        <g id="success-pebble-icon">
          <g>
            <circle class="circle" r="9.1" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.8" cx="12" cy="12" fill="none" transform="rotate(-90 12 12)"></circle>
            <path d="M15.667,8L17,9.042l-5.316,7.36c-0.297,0.395-0.739,0.594-1.184,0.599c-0.455,0.005-0.911-0.195-1.215-0.599l-2.441-3.456l1.416-1.028l2.227,3.167L15.667,8z" fill="currentColor"></path>
            <rect style="fill:none;" width="24" height="24"></rect>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id="Layer_1">
        </g>
      </g></svg></li-icon>
    <p class="artdeco-toast-message">
              Invitation sent to xxxxx
        <button class="action" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-3995="3995">
          Visualizar perfil
        </button>

    </p>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Wait for the element to be visible and try the same code.. A guess.

Comment: @Paulo, What you getting as output ? complete text including button text ? or any error ?

Comment: @Tuks 
I get the full text, even what's inside the button, which is text irrelevant to me.

Comment: @santhoshkumar 
I already do it rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact Selenium's getText() method retrieves all the text in sub elements too, so the approach, recommended by **Murthi** is the most applicable, as far as I know.
Try this approach:

```
String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String pessoapopu = driver.findElement(By.className("artdeco-toast-message"))
                           .getText().replaceAll(newLine, "");
```

Or *try/ask for* more convenient HTML code.

Comment: is there any way to handle this using only xpath ?

Comment: I'm thinking of 'and not()' xpath method, but not sure about it.

Comment: This doesn't do what OP asked... I'm not sure why it's marked as the answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `//p[@class='artdeco-toast-message']/text()` xpath to locate the **`Invitation sent to xxxxx`** text but selenium doesn't support `text()` method in xpath to locate a text node.

Either if you try to locate the element using below xpath to exclude the button text by using `not()` function of xpath :

```
//p[@class='artdeco-toast-message']/node()[not(self::button)]
```

Again it locating the element using text node so Selenium doesn't allow this

Here one solution available to execute same xpath i.e. `JavascriptExecutor`

Use `evaluate()` method of `JavaScript` and evaluate your xpath using `JavascriptExecutor`

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
Object message = js.executeScript("var value = document.evaluate(\"//p[@class='artdeco-toast-message']/text()\",document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null ); return value.stringValue;");
System.out.println(message.toString().trim());
```

> OR

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
Object message = js.executeScript("var value = document.evaluate(\"//p[@class='artdeco-toast-message']/node()[not(self::button)]\",document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null ); return value.stringValue;");
System.out.println(message.toString().trim());
```

It will give you the expected result. No need to get all data and then formatting using String functions.

You can explore `evaluate()` in detail [from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following code.

```
WebElement text=driver.findElement(By.className("artdeco-toast-message"));
String wholeText = text.getText();
String unWantedText=text.findElement(By.className("action")).getText();
String RequiredText=wholeText.replace(unWantedText,"");
System.out.println(RequiredText);
```

Comment: Did not work "The method getText() is undefined for the type By"

Comment: It worked in parts, it is tripling the mesnagem in the console:
Invitation sent to Mauro Santos
Invitation sent to Mauro Santos
Invitation sent to Mauro Santos


and it does not find the element in the next pass
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"action"}

Comment: may be the button with the class name "action" is not there in the next pass. You can check the html code or give us the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML, you should be able to `.getText()`, split that text on a newline, and then take the first split to get the text you want.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.artdeco-toast-message")).getText().split("\r\n")[0];
```