# How to locate a name using xpath out of three items?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I've written an xpath to locate a name from th tag but the thing is there are three items attached within a "th" tag separated by "br" tag. How to locate only the first item which is in this case the name among three? Here is what I tried with:

```
//td[@class='data']/table//th
```

Elements within the items are:

```
<td class="data" valign="top" nowrap="">

                                        <table width="350">

                                            <tbody><tr>    
                                                <td valign="top" nowrap="">Owner Name &amp;<br>Mailing Address:</td>
                                                <th align="left" valign="top" nowrap="">

                                                <!-- ---------- OWNER NAME ---------- -->
                                                PADILLA ISAI &amp; JOSEFINA<br>


                                                <!-- ---------- MAILING ADDRESS ---------- -->

                                                        <!-- ---------- MAILING ADDRESS (MAIL TO) ---------- -->


                                                        <!-- ---------- MAILING ADDRESS (ADDR1 AND ADDR2) ---------- -->
                                                        8227 FINDLAY ST<br>


                                                        <!--
                                                        ------------------------------------------------
                                                        'RA 09/11/2012: 
                                                            Changed order of Owner / Address to :

                                                                Owner Name(s)
                                                                MailTo
                                                                Addr_1
                                                                Addr_2
                                                                City
                                                                State
                                                                Zip
                                                                Country
                                                        ------------------------------------------------
                                                        8227 FINDLAY ST
                                                        ------------------------------------------------
                                                        -->

                                                        <!-- ---------- MAILING ADDRESS (CITY-STATE-ZIP OR COUNTRY)---------- -->
                                                        HOUSTON&nbsp;TX&nbsp;77017-2328<br>

                                                            <!--<br />-->


                                               </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody></table>

                                    </td>
```

With my expression the result I'm getting is:

```
DURAN FRANCISCO & AURORA
4010 BALMORHEA AVE
HOUSTON TX 77039-2510
```

But I expect to get only:

```
DURAN FRANCISCO & AURORA
```

In general cases I would probably go for:

```
//td[@class='data']/table//th/text()[1]
```

But, selenium doesn't support text indexing either. What can I do to get the name only from the th tag?

Comment: Can you try this..-->//td[@class='data']/table//th[1]

Comment: IMO, while preparing the sample `HTML` the `DOM` format got broken. I can see the `td` and `br` tags overlapping each other. `<td valign="top" nowrap="">Owner Name &amp;<br>Mailing Address:</td>
<th align="left" valign="top" nowrap="">

<!-- ---------- OWNER NAME ---------- -->
PADILLA ISAI &amp; JOSEFINA<br>` Am I missing something?

Comment: I tried to make it look slightly nice. Gonna update with how it was originally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code and let me know in case it won't return expected result:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='data']/table//th")
print(driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent", element).strip())
```

Comment: I was expecting  :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the following way to execute the xpath which doesn't supported by selenium directly :

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
Object message = js.executeScript("var value = document.evaluate(\"//td[@class='data']/table//th/text()[1]\",document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null ); return value.stringValue;");
System.out.println(message.toString());
```

Still having issue let me know :)

Get more details from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45303767/get-some-text-with-java-selenium-webdriver/45318212#45318212)

Comment: Have u imported the `import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;` package ? u r using java right ?

Comment: Sorry sir, I'm using python.

Comment: can you try like `driver.execute_script("var value = document.evaluate(\"//td[@class='data']/table//th/text()[1]\",document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null ); return value.stringValue;");` and use the value returned by the same

Comment: Trying hard to fit it in my python script.