# Python Selenium search for [object Text]

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, html-parsing

This is my selenium code below.

```
sourcesearch = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=\"Table_Exame\"]/tbody/tr[1]/td/text()[1]')
```

And the result is -

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid
>   selector: The result of the xpath expression
>   "//*[@id="Table_Exame"]/tbody/tr[1]/td/text()[1]" is: [object Text].
>   It should be an element.

Would there be any ways I can retrieve [object Text] via Selenium?
Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Anything other than Xpath weren't available since the site did not add any tags for the text.
Also, sorry for not being able to include the site address since it's only a member only website.

Comment: You can try to get text content with `sourcesearch = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=\"Table_Exame\"]/tbody/tr[1]/td).text` and then parse it to extract required sub-string. Or execute JavaScript just like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45563475/how-to-locate-a-name-using-xpath-out-of-three-items/45564733#45564733)

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the way. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, found this while searching.

For me, truncating the xpath from

```
//*[@id='form_main_step3']/li[2]/div/label[2]/text()
```

to

```
//*[@id='form_main_step3']/li[2]/div/label[2]
```

solved my problem.

I've also found care required to inspect the correct DOM element is needed. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

As your XPath expression terminates with `text()[whatever]`, this resolves to a text container, and not an HTML element (or list of).

Hint: try your XPath expression in the Firefox console with `$x(some_xpath_expression)` while browsing the page.

Perhaps you should edit your question and add the surrounding HTML excerpt and describe precisely what you expect.

Comment: Hmm. I think it would be rather better off parsing the whole HTML via BeautifulSoup.
The Surrounding HTML was just <body> itself. That's why I didn't post the HTML source.

Comment: If the content is not built with JS (React, Angular, ...) processing with Beautifulsoup and lxml will be faster if you're scraping tons of pages, in addition debugging will be easier.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying BeautifulSoup now. I just didn't like the idea of importing too many modules.

Answer (score 0):

It could be solved with the help of a method `document.evaluate()` from JavaScript.

Pure JavaScript:

`var element = document.evaluate("//*[local-name() = 'text'][@x='8']/text()", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;if (element) {return element.nodeValue;}`

Here is the example for **Java** (I am afraid of giving in Python as far as I could make a mistake without execution. And the code is from the working project in Java):

```
    String textObjectXpath = "\"//*[local-name() = 'text'][@x='8']/text()\"";
    String script = "var element = document.evaluate("
            + textObjectXpath
            + ", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;"
            + "if (element) {return element.nodeValue;}";
    String extractedText = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(script);
```

The if statement `"if (element) {return element.nodeValue;}"` could be omitted if you don't care about the scenario when the element is without text. In such a case, you may want to replace the line with `"return element.nodeValue;"`