# How to extract text between 2 same child tags of a parent tag

Tags: selenium, xpath

Below is the html markup and I want to extract mobile number 7788996655 using xpath:-

```
<table class="table hover" id="resultTable">
 <tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td class="left">
            <img src="/symfony/web/index.php/pim/viewPhoto/gamerNumber/1/from/gameDir" height="200" width="196">
        </td>
        <td class="left">
            <span style="font-weight:bold;">John Player</span>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <br>
            <span style="font-weight:bold;">Email: </span>
            <a href="john.player@yyeett.com">john.player@yyeett.com</a>, 
            <span style="font-weight:bold;">
            Mobile: </span>7788996655, 
            <span style="font-weight:bold;">Skype: </span>
            game.player,
            <br>
            <span style="font-weight:bold;">Designation: </span> 
            Moderator,  
            <br> 
            <span style="font-weight:bold;">Game Name: </span>
            Counter Strike
            <br>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried below xpath, but it didn't worked:

```
//td/span[contains(.,'Mobile:')]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Can someone provide solution for this?

Workaround I tried is to get whole text within **td** and then used pattern matching regex to extract mobile number from it. But, now i want to know whether is it possible using xpath?

Comment: If you use `selenium` you'll not be able to use XPath that returns text node.

Comment: @Andersson Interesting, what's wrong with using Xpath Andy?

Comment: Can you please format the HTML as it is in the HTML DOM?

Comment: @DebanjanB, In `selenium` XPath should return WebElement only, but not text node or attribute. Provided XPath intend to return `text()`. This will not work

Comment: @Andersson Agreed XPath returns Node. So what's wrong with retrieving text or any attribute from the Node?

Comment: @DebanjanB, getting text content of `td` with, for example, `text` property (Python) or `getText()` method (Java) should return not only mobile number, but also `"John Player"`, `"Email: "`, etc... OP should try in this case to execute JavaScript to get required text node and to avoid using regex...

Comment: @Andersson I wish OP formats the HTML properly. I am willing to take a shot at it. Yeah using JS sounds like a solution but I am still a newbie in that frame.

Comment: @DebanjanB - Hi, I have  formatted the HTML. Hope you can give a try now.

Comment: @Andersson - Thanks for the explanantion!!

Comment: Whats wrong with the `<br>` tags, why aren't they closed? Look at the `<img>` tag, thats not closed even. Have you copied the HTML as it is?

Comment: @DebanjanB, `br` doesn't need closing tag. As well as `img`

Comment: Which Selenium binding? Java/Python?

Comment: @VishalJagtap, check this alternative and let me know if worthy for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45303767/get-some-text-with-java-selenium-webdriver/45318212#45318212

Comment: @Tuks - Thanks for the link. Javascript is working for me too. But, I was just hoping can it be done using xpath.

Comment: @VishalJagtap, As far as i know it won't allow to locate the element using text node in xpath in selenium

Comment: @VishalJagtap Can you share the website url incase a public IP?

Comment: @DebanjanB Its not public IP. But i have made sure that i have given complete required html markup

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using below XPath

```
<parent td node xpath>/text()[preceding-sibling::span[1][text() = 'Mobile: ']]
```

Now for an explanation. `/td/text()` will select each text which is part of the td node but is not part of any other node. So in this case it `,`,`7788996655,`, `game.player`, `moderator`.

Now out of these 4 text we want to filter out one which has a previous sibling, which is a span and has text `Mobile:`, so we can add `[preceding-sibling::span[1][text()='Mobile: ']]`

Comment: Paste the complete xpath you used