# selenium - get parent text using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I use selenium to parse a html, but have trouble getting only the parent text. The html snippet looks like:

```
<p>
  <span>Who</span>
  Mario
</p>
```

I get the element with

```
div.find_element_by_xpath('p/span[contains(text/(), "Who")]../').text.strip()
```

But this returns all text ("Who Mario") inside the p tag.
How can i only retrieve the parent text (Mario) without .replace(), etc?

Comment: Use this xpath `//p/text()['Mario']/preceding-sibling::span` . But selenium doesn't allow you to locate an element using text node. for solution you have to use `execute_script` in python to execute your xpath query and then get the result. Refer this for more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45303767/get-some-text-with-java-selenium-webdriver/45318212#45318212

Comment: NarendraR is very correct, if you want to directly get that text you have to use execute_script, please try `ele_p=driver.finde_element_by_xpath('//p[contains(. ,"Who")]');print driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', ele_p)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
div.find_element_by_xpath('p/span[contains(text(), "Who")]/following-sibling::text()').text.strip()
```

Comment: Hm, I get `invalid selector is: [object Text]. It should be an element`